# Slicing a 2d array in python via another array in one line

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

Apologies is the title is not correct. I didn't know how to describe exactly what I am looking for.
So coming from Matlab I want to be able to do the following in Python in one line if possible

Say I have an index array:

`index_array= np.array([0,1,1,0,0,0,1])`

and a data array:
`data_array = np.zeros([len(index_array),2])`

I want to place a value (e.g. 100) where index_array=0 to the data_array[:,0] and where index_array=1 to data_array[:,1]

I matlab you could do it with one line. Something like
`data_array(index_array)=100`

The best I could figure out in python is this

`data_array [index_array==0,0]=100`

`data_array [index_array==1,1]=100`

Is it possible to do it more efficiently (w.r.t. lines of code). Also it would be nice to scale for additional dimensions in data_array (beyond 2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, please try this:

```
import numpy as np
index_array= np.array([0,1,1,0,0,0,1],dtype=bool)
data_array = np.zeros([len(index_array),2])
data_array[index_array,:]=100
print(data_array)
```

Here, `index_array` is instantiated as boolean. Or it can convert `index_array` to boolean using `==` (`index_array==0`).

Use `data_array[index_array,...]=100` if there are additional dimensions.

**------ CORRECTED VERSION ------**

Hope I now understand your question. So try this:

```
import numpy as np
index_array= np.array([0,1,1,0,2,0,1,2])
data_array = np.zeros([len(index_array),3])

data_array[np.arange(len(index_array)), index_array] = 100

print(data_array)
```

Comment: ok this works. I guess I omitted the boolean type thats why mine didnt work. However, I am not sure this naturally extends to more than 2 dimensions? Say, index_array= np.array([0,1,1,0,2,0,1,2],dtype=bool)   and data_array = np.zeros([len(index_array),3]). Then using data_array[index_array,:]=100 produces the wrong result.   Because when casting the index_array to boolean, anything nonzero becomes true.

Comment: Please read the end of my answer "Use `data_array[index_array,...]=100` if there are additional dimensions."

Comment: I did. I used this data_array[index_array,...]= 100 verbatim but I got the same result as before. The problem comes from setting index_array= np.array([0,1,1,0,2,0,1,2],dtype=bool)   because 1 and 2 are the same from the boolean point of view

Comment: Ok, I understand that's a slightly different question. See corrected version in my answer.